# Why i can't put my three divs into one row?

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 33.3%;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

now my three divs are not in same line. The div with number 3 goes into new line. Why is that ?
I setted the parent to have 100% width, my three divs 33.3% so they should fit inside the 100% width container.

Where is the problem ?

Comment: In the white space _between_ those inline-block elements, which will get condensed to the width of one space character. And 100% plus two times x is more than 100%, for any x > 0.

Comment: it's already asked much time if you do a little google you can solve this issue.

Comment: @CBroe from where are this spaces coming from when i don't set margin ?

Comment: From the whitespace between the tags. Between `</div>` and `<div class="box">`, you have a line break, and tabs/spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a flexbox.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.box {
    background: grey;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 33.3%;
    display: inline-block;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="box">1</div>
        <div class="box">2</div>
        <div class="box">3</div>
    </div>
```

Use `display: flex` to make your parent container a flexbox. Use `justify-content: space-evenly;` to allocate space evenly to each object so that they fit next to eachother.

This should do the job :)

Answer (score -1):

The spaces are causing your issue, this article explains why in detail: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/. To cure this instantly, simply put your divs on one line:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  text-align:center;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="box">1</div><div class="box">2</div><div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's happening due to space between HTML elements as @CBroe said follow this link[check here](http://How%20do%20I%20remove%20the%20space%20between%20inline/inline-block%20elements?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
 .parent {
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width:33.3%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent"><div class="box">1</div><div class="box">2</div><div class="box">3</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not downvoted, but the link - check here is not working

Comment: the run code snippet you can see 123 are inline.